# Are there any shader inputs other than TEXCOORD that wpf supports

Tags: wpf, effects, shader, hlsl

I know that you can tie constant registers to dependency properties as well as tie a brush to a sampler, but every example I have seen of a wpf shader uses the declaration

main( float2 uv : TEXCOORD  ) : COLOR

I am a complete newbie to HLSL but I know there are other semantics than TEXCOORD. Can any of them be used with a WPF shader?

Similarly are there any valid returns that can be used other than the semantic COLOR?

Or are the semantics just "reminders" to the user and WPF will run whatever shader it receives as if it has TEXCOORD inputs and a COLOR output regardless (and will choke on a float4 or struct input)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the excellent [tutorial by Greg Schechter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2008/05/12/introduction-to-writing-effects.aspx), WPF only supports a main method with that signature.  Although that was written before PS3 support, I don't think anything has changed in this regard.